# 3ds max connect vertices to edges

Tags: 3ds-max

It is same editable poly, How to connect this 2 parts into solid geometry

[image]

Comment: Please what do you want to connect? The white lines? The arrows?

Comment: the white lines

Comment: There is a proposal (future stackexchange site) dedicated to 3D, called [3D Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-graphics-modeling-animation?referrer=4bIZIhmQJeWKQcyqcR7pKw2). Your question matches its scope 100%, have a look at it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, you are looking for `Bridge` command, which build a segment of pipe. Then you should switch to the `Border` sublevel, select both borders and click `Bridge`. Using this command's setting allows to manage segments, twists and so on.

It also might be that you want to weld verticies together. In this case you have to place vertecies close enough to each other, select them and press `Weld`. Choose appropriate `threshold` value to ensure that only the verticies you need have been welded together.

By the way, it's unclear what you're doing because you are using orthographic projection. Press 'P' to use perspective.